# Pass props from a component to a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, react-props

I have a drawer navigator with two buttons on it. When I click the login button, I want to remove from cache the Authentication token and to change screen to the Login one.

```
function doSomething(props) {
AsyncStorage.removeItem(AUTH_EMAIL);
AsyncStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
props.navigation.navigate("Login")
}

const CustomContentComponent = (props) => (

<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}}
                          onPress={() => 
props.navigation.navigate("About")}>
            <Text style={mainStyles.blackBigFont}>About</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1}}
                          onPress={doSomething.bind(props)}>
            <Text style={mainStyles.blackBigFont}>Login Page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard,
    },
    About: {
        screen: About,
    },
},
{
    contentComponent: CustomContentComponent
});
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: undefined is not an object ( evaluating `props.navigation.navigate`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your function inside component, and use ES6 syntax for method then you will not need to bind `this`

```
const CustomContentComponent = props => {
  doSomething = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem(AUTH_EMAIL);
    AsyncStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("About")}
        >
          <Text style={mainStyles.blackBigFont}>About</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={doSomething}>
          <Text style={mainStyles.blackBigFont}>Login Page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn`t seems to work. Unresolved variable or type error if I put the method insde the component.

Comment: did you changed round braces to Curly braces  and used return method to return component ?